# Slicknav autoclosing multilevel menus

Tags: javascript, html, navigationbar, slicknav

I'm working with slicknav for my mobile menu. I came across a cool little way to have the Parent menu close automatically if you click on another Parent menu and I have it working perfectly if I'm using it like below (please note, i do not know javascript. What you see is me hacking some together from other code I've found online):

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="first"><a href="#">Parent1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="">Child1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="">Child2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" title="">Parent2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="">Child3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="">Child4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" title="">Parent3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="">Child5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="">Child6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#menu').slicknav({
            label: 'MENU',
            duration: 150,
            allowParentLinks: true,
            'open': function(trigger){
            var that = trigger.parent().children('ul');
            $('.slicknav_menu ul li.slicknav_open ul').each(function(){
                if($(this).get( 0 ) != that.get( 0 )){
                    $(this).slideUp().addClass('slicknav_hidden');
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('slicknav_open').addClass('slicknav_collapsed');
                 }
             })
        },
        closeOnClick:true
        });
    });

    $("#content").click(function(){
        $('#menu').slicknav('close');
    });
</script>
```

I'm needing to make some of the children items have their own dropdowns. Is there a way to make the javascript function with the same idea? If it is unchanged, when you tap/click on any of the children items with their own ul li items, it opens, then immediately closes.

if I remove this:

```
var that = trigger.parent().children('ul');
            $('.slicknav_menu ul li.slicknav_open ul').each(function(){
                if($(this).get( 0 ) != that.get( 0 )){
                    $(this).slideUp().addClass('slicknav_hidden');
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('slicknav_open').addClass('slicknav_collapsed');
                 }
             })
```

then the autoclosing stops. Parent and children/parents remain open.

I'd like to be able to tap the children/parent and have it remain open unless you're tapping on another children/parent item. I'm sorry if i'm not making sense. Tired and this is about the best I can do....

As stated at the beginning of this post, javascript is not my language... Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated.